# Error when phablet-flash -b

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I follow the instruction here http://blog.desdelinux.net/como-instalar-ubuntu-touch/.

But when I try `phablet-flash -b` throw the follow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/phablet-flash", line 22, in <module>
    from phabletutils import arguments
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phabletutils/arguments.py", line 23, in <module>
    from phabletutils import cdimage
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phabletutils/cdimage.py", line 25, in <module>
    from phabletutils import fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/phabletutils/fileutils.py", line 20, in <module>
    import lzma
ImportError: No module named lzma
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue we just noticed, for the time being do:

> sudo apt-get install python-lzma

That'll install the missing python module.

Comment: A fixed package has now been uploaded.